# Alienware m15x (older model) BSOD investigation

Tags: windows-7, troubleshooting, bsod

A friend of mine asked me to help him with an Alienware m15x laptop that had a little service history.

It was bought in June 2008, serviced in January 2009 for a random FPS drop problem. Alienware returned it saying nothing was wrong. The laptop still had hiccups, but after juggling a few drivers and settings, the FPS drops weren't as noticeable.

Eventually it died in Sept. 2009. It would not boot up locking itself on a white/gray screen. (I think it was overheating .. clocking in 100 degrees Celsius).

So back to Alienware it went. They replaced the GPU and all was fine. 
Up until these blue screens started showing up.

One other thing that was updated was the HDD and a Windows 7 reinstall, in August. From then on it seems to have started its BSOD. Could this be the culprit?

The original Windows was Vista but it was upgraded with a digital download/purchase of Windows 7 Home Premium and activated after installing windows. No errors on the old HDD, just on the latest installation.

LE:Due note that now the old HDD is used to see if issues re-occur.

So please, I am in need of someone who can interpret these windows dump files:
[Minidump](http://www.megaupload.com/?d=9KAJWWUV)

I may have come to some conflicting conclusions.
So if someone can clarify each dump/date and the probable cause/error it had; and a final conclusion or solution, we would be very grateful.

Also please consult report for other system info I omitted: same link,code: XRWIVLWG

If I missed something or if you have any other questions I'll be happy to answer them.

```
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU T9300 @ 2.50GHz 

Network Adapter Properties:
  Broadcom NetLink (TM) Gigabit Ethernet
  Intel(R) Wireless WiFi Link 4965AGN

Video Adapter Properties:
  Driver Description                                NVIDIA GeForce 8800M GTX
  Driver Date                                       19.08.2009
  Driver Version                                    8.16.11.8681
  Driver Provider                                   NVIDIA
  INF File                                          oem19.inf
  Hardware ID                                       PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_060C&SUBSYS_0770152D&REV_A2
  Location Information                              @system32\DRIVERS\pci.sys,#65536;PCI bus %1, device %2, function %3;(1,0,0)
  PCI Device                                        NVIDIA GeForce 8800M GTX [NoDB]
  BIOS String                                       Version 62.92.34.0.8
  Installed Drivers                                 nvd3dum (8.16.11.8681), nvwgf2um, nvwgf2um

Hard Dik Drive:
  Model ID                                          ST9120823ASG (**older one 120gb**)
  Model ID                                          WD32000BEKT (new 320gb with fresh OS)
```

Comment: I have had the same problems with my dell xps m1730 with same T9300 proc and 2 graphic cards in SLI (8800M GTX SLI). First time when all started, the windows cannot work in SLI mode on adapter, but not in SLI all was fine (in Win7 x64). Then i replaced my video cards through dell's warranty and problem was solves for one month :D this time the windows cannot work with video cards enabled (i need it manually disable in device manager), to use my laptop :)... as soon as I replaced cards the second time, I decided to find way to run GPU's fan in 100% mode. I8kfanGUI was the great solution :)

Comment: Here is the link: http://www.diefer.de/i8kfan/

Comment: P.S. now i'm playing a long time SC2 (1920x1200 ultra), Mafia (1920x1200 AAx2 high), CoD: Black Ops (1920x1200 AAx2 high) .... and seems to be no overheat (stable 60-65C) and no BSOD after 5-10 hours playing.

Comment: ahh forgot :) i'm using also ZALMAN notebook cooler ZM-NC2000, but i had it when the video cards was first time crashed :)

Comment: The minidump download link is broken

Answer (score 1):

Did a fresh reinstall on the new HDD and all seems quiet now. Something definitely went wrong with the first install and caused all those BSOD.

Current drivers are:
1. Intel Chipset Drivers - Latest online drivers from Intel website

2. NVIDIA Display Drivers - 186.81 win 7 32 bit, NVIDIA website (best one found, over 190+ are nogo)
3. PhysX 9.09.0814
4. Audio Drivers - Realtek, Win7_R254
5. OSD Utility - M15x_OSD_Vista_00020 (Alienware)
6. Synaptic Touchpad Drivers - Synaptics v14.0.3 Win7
7. Media Card Reader Drivers - M15x_MediaReader_Vista_3.51.01
8. Turbo Memory Drivers + Matrix Storage - Latest online drivers from Intel website
9. Bluetooth Drivers - M15x_Bluetooth_vista_6.0.1.5100
10. Latest DirectX

Network drivers installed by Windows. After installing all Drivers, ran Windows Update.